# Определите, пуст ли объект

Tags: javascript

```js
var schedule = {
  name: "Петя",
  user: 'Root',
  password: 333,
  age: 20
};


function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var key in schedule) {
    return console.log(false);
  }
  return console.log(true);
}
isEmpty(schedule);
```

***Правильное решение  или можно, но это не значит, что нужно так делать ?***

Создайте функцию `isEmpty(obj)`, которая возвращает `true`, если в объекте нет свойств и `false` – если хоть одно свойство есть.

Comment: неправильное: твоя функция всегда возвращает undefined

Comment: Air, спасибо бро

Comment: `return Object.keys(x).length == 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  return Object.keys(x).length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение неверное, так как **всегда** возвращает `undefined`.

Вместо этого нужно возвращать результат:

```js
var schedule = {
  name: "Петя",
  user: 'Root',
  password: 333,
  age: 20
};


function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var key in schedule) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(isEmpty(schedule));
```

Кроме этого не совсем ясен момент с присутствием свойств в прототипе объекта, если они не должны учитываться, то нужно добавить дополнительную проверку с [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

---

Альтернативным решением может быть использование [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) либо [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), однако в этом случае вместо простой проверки наличия, сначала будет получен список всех свойств и лишь затем проверка его длины.

---

Еще один подводный камень: наличие в объекте не перечисляемых свойств.

Если их наличие так же должно учитываться, вместо `for..in` или `Object.keys` нужно воспользоваться [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)